# Parse XML to Tuple

Tags: c#, linq

New to LINQ.
Example xml:

```
<item name="XX">
    <inside type="A"/>
    <inside type="B" />
</item>
<item name="YY">
    <inside type="C"/>
    <inside type="D" />
</item>
```

I would like to parse it to tuples:

```
(XX, A)
(XX, B)
(YY, C)
(YY, D)
```

So far I can retrieve the first lines online: `(XX, A)` and `(YY, C)` of each item using the code below:

```
var selected = (from item in doc.Root.Elements()
let inside = item.Element(XName.Get("inside", item.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName))
select Tuple.Create(item.Attribute("name").Value,
inside.Attribute("type").Value)).ToList();
```

I believe I should modify `item.Element` to `item.Elements` but so far no luck.

Comment: Don't know if it's of any significance but you're missing a closing " after inside elements B and D so you're example XML isn't well formed

Comment: Was just typo. No significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `item.Element` you should iterate over `item.Elements`:

```
var selected = (from item in doc.Root.Elements()
                from inside in item.Elements("inside")
                select Tuple.Create(
                       item.Attribute("name").Value,
                       inside.Attribute("type").Value)
               ).ToList();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew it's `.ElementS`, but was not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tuples = XElement.Parse(xml).Descendants("item")
    .SelectMany(item => item.Elements()
        .Select(inside => Tuple.Create(item.Attribute("name"), inside.Attribute("type"))));
```

You can use `SelectMany` to help you build a collection of tuples from a single element.